# Frequency increase due to equivalence principle vs gravitational attraction

Tags: general-relativity, doppler-effect, equivalence-principle

In [Volume II Chapter 42](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_42.html) (on General Relativity), Feynman uses the equivalence principle to show that clocks etc. higher in a gravitational field run faster, and as a result emit photons with higher frequency .

Then he says that this can be demonstrated in two other ways:

**a)** via conservation of energy: an atom in excited state $E_1$ is lifted and emits a photon towards the ground. The photon must have a higher frequency to compensate for the lesser energy (re)gained by lowering the atom that is now in state $E_0$

**b)** the gravitational pull on the photon has the effect of increasing its frequency

It seems to me that **b)** itself should explain **a)** independent of General Relativity (using SR alone), and that the equivalence principle should *compound* the frequency increase (effectively doubling it). How can in it be used to demonstrate the effects of the equivalence principle?